# On the measure of regular and chaotic regions in a phase space

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, hamiltonian-mechanics, chaos

Consider a Hamiltonian, non-linear, dynamical system associated to $H(\vec{q},\vec{p})$. Assume that the number of effective degrees of freedom is relatively small, say $D=3,4,5$. Now choose a certain initial state $(\vec{q}_0,\vec{p}_0)$ which univocally identifies a constant-energy hypersurface of the type $H=E_0$.

In general, on such hypersurface, chaotic and regular orbits are present. Is it possible to give an estimate of their relative measure? Do regular islands always exist? Is it reasonable to conjecture that the size of regular islands shrinks as the number of degrees of freedom $D$ increases? Is it reasonable to conjecture that if $D\to+\infty$, then regular islands disappear and the system becomes practically ergodic?

Comment: These questions are THE main (and quite open) questions in dynamical systems field. You can begin by reading about KAM theorem and ergodic hypothesis.

Comment: I apologize if my question was too naive, but I am from the Physics community. I know standard notions of dynamical systems, but i don’t know what is known and what is open. So, none of my questions has an answer? Do these two conjectures already exist? I mean: have they been actually formulated and are people trying to prove them?

Comment: Basically, some of the questions you ask have been answered for some class of systems. The notion of a "generic" nonlinear system are hard to capture for example. Here's a good resource for some quick overview: https://www.math.ucla.edu/dls/amie-wilkinson

Comment: Thanks for the videos. I'm going to watch them. Actually, I'm not specifically interested in specific classes of systems, but I would like to get a general, intuitive picture of the scenario. So, as far as I've understood, it *is* reasonable to *conjecture* that the size of regular islands decreases if $D$ increases.  Despite not proven in general, is what people expect to happen?

Comment: What you conjecture is essentially the ergodic hypothesis. And it is now understood that it has to be false in many classes of systems, and true in many others.